# Turn third-party method with callbacks into promise

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with turning some callback-based code into promise-based. It is for payment provider Chargify. So the code looks like this and it is not waiting for results. E.g. when we call `chargify.token()` the execution goes further and only afterwards callbacks `success` or `error` are called.

```
chargify.token(
     form,
     function success(token) {
                    
     },
     function error(err) {

     }
);
```

What I want to do is to wrap this call into a Promise and resolve that promise when `success` is executed.

I started from wrapping it into `async function token() {}` which did not help obviously.

Comment: Try `const fn = form => new Promise((resolve, reject) => chargify.token(form, resolve, reject))`

Comment: @HaoWu but where the code from old callbacks go? Do I call this like fn(form).then(//code from success callback//).then(//code from error callback//)

Comment: Yes, when function in `.then()` is called meaning `success` callback has been triggered. You may also want to chain a `.catch(/* code from error callback */)`.

Comment: @HaoWu Thanks!
It seems to make sense. And it is working for `then` buf for `catch` I get an error `then(...).catch() is not a function`

Comment: Make sure you're passing a function but not the expression itself: `fn(form).then(() => { /* code from success block */ }).catch(() => { /* code from error block */ })`

Comment: But it's recommended to use it asynchronously: `try { const token = await fn(form); /* code from success block */; } catch(err) { /* code from error block */ }`

Comment: @HaoWu thanks!
I resolved my issue. Instead of your solution I used $.deferred fro jQuery to create a promise. And for rejected flow it has `fail` instead if `catch`